# How is Lord DeRosso immortal?

Tags: bravely-default

If you explore Vampire Castle, you'll ultimately learn that Lord DeRosso gained his immortality while burning in his own castle's flames - when some dark voice offered him power everlasting.

During the final battle, Lord DeRosso makes an appearance: before sacrificing himself against Lord Ouroboros, he recites the same words as the dark voice - then he fuses with Ouroboros' core.

But, this still doesn't quite explain Lord DeRosso's immortality - nor is it very clear why did he recite those words (obviously he's the dark voice his past self heard, but I still don't see the point).

So, what exactly makes Lord DeRosso immortal?

Comment: He's probably immortal by the power of that unknown "dark voice". Reciting the words may just have been a way to "strip" himself of his immortality the same way he obtained it (?). I've not found anything that hints at how or why he's immortal.

Answer (score 2):

I actually don't recall directly either; and I'm not sure it was ever clearly explained.
It's an interesting chain of events I can't get straight in my head:

- DeRosso becomes immortal when he sets his home ablaze and hears the voice
- The voice is actually DeRosso speaking during the final battle (beginning the bootstrap paradox)
- During the battle with Sage (1800 years prior to the story's events); he's given a task by the angel only he can complete due to being an immortal

So I guess he somehow was able to make himself immortal?

I'm pulling this from the [final fantasy wiki](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Lester_DeRosso):

> Forced to watch the innocents trapped in his manor suffer a lingering
>   death by starvation, DeRosso set his home on fire with the intent to
>   go down with it. Just as he was about to die, beginning to come to the
>   realization that his persecution is unwarranted and that those
>   responsible must pay, DeRosso heard a voice call out to him: "Accept
>   me and I shall grant life everlasting. Though it shall be filled with
>   grief, thou shalt have all eternity to wreak vengeance upon thine
>   enemies". While the voice's identity was unknown to him at the time,
>   DeRosso became an immortal and left the ruins of his home. Demonized
>   as a vampire by the Orthodoxy, deciding to make use their propaganda
>   by giving himself the look, DeRosso gathered many followers who shared
>   his malice towards the Orthodoxy.
>
> In the final world, with Ouroboros's arrival into his reality, DeRosso
>   carries out his promise to the angel by merging into the monster's
>   core. Using his own immortality to negate Ouroboros's regeneration,
>   DeRosso dies with the monster when he is finally destroyed. But prior
>   to his sacrifice, as the Infernal Realm transcends time and space,
>   DeRosso begins a [bootstrap paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_paradox) by saying the very words he heard
>   long ago so that a past version of himself would hear it.

Comment: Maybe he gave his old self Ouroboros's immortality, assuming it had to go somewhere? But yea, they don't really explain it.